# How to make Modifier panel visible in Toolshelve

Tags: python, scripting, interface

```
import bpy 

from bpy.types import Menu, Panel, UIList

class View3DPanel(): 
  bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D' 
  bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'


class OpenStudioAddRigPanel(View3DPanel, Panel): 
 bl_label = "Test" 
 bl_context = "objectmode" 
 bl_category = "Test" 


def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    ob = context.object

    layout.operator_menu_enum("object.modifier_add", "type")

    for md in ob.modifiers:
        box = layout.template_modifier(md)
        if box:
            # match enum type to our functions, avoids a lookup table.
            getattr(self, md.type)(box, ob, md)


def register(): bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
def unregister(): bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__": register()
print("Add Rig loaded")
```

So I try to learn how I could move the modifier stack into the tool shelve so I can work full screen without the need of the button menu.

I am totally new at UI scripting and scripting in general with Blender, so I am looking for some guidance and tips what to do. I managed to make some modifier related stuff appear in the tool shelve but it does not list all added modifiers and such.

[image]

So I looked into: "properties_data_modifier.py"
This defines for example a boolean modifier operation but I fail to see how
I could also get this running in the tool shelve. Sad me ;)

```
def BOOLEAN(self, layout, ob, md):
    split = layout.split()

    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Operation:")
    col.prop(md, "operation", text="")

    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Object:")
    col.prop(md, "object", text="")
```

So to sum it up: what I try to look for is the ability to list all added modifiers in the 3D view port tool panel and in addition enable you to edit them.

I did a quick hack and edited the modifier py script and it all can be displayed in the tool panel - so technically this is possible. Can somebody tell me how one could include this as a class in a new script?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The panel displaying the modifiers includes methods with names matching every modifier type that are used to display the properties of the matching modifier, `getattr()` is used to find the matching method based on the type of modifier in the objects modifier list.

While inheriting the modifiers panel directly causes issues, you can create a local instance of the panel and make use of the methods it contains.

```
import bpy
from bl_ui.properties_data_modifier import DATA_PT_modifiers

class myModifiersPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Object Modifiers"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_mymodifiers"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modifiers"

    def draw(self, context):
        mp = DATA_PT_modifiers(context)
        layout = self.layout
        ob = context.object
        row = layout.row()

        if not ob.modifiers:
            row.label('No modifiers')
        else:
            for md in ob.modifiers:
                box = layout.template_modifier(md)
                if box:
                    getattr(mp, md.type)(box, ob, md)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(myModifiersPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(myModifiersPanel)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Sad that I was not able to figure thus out myself as this looks very logical. grrrr