# Confused about how to define a class

Tags: python, interface

This is how I sofar define a class for a panel inside the tool shelve.

```
class ObjectLayer(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "ObjectLayer"
    bl_idname = "ObjectLayer"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Claas"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj , "layers")
```

Then I got this amazing script in how to show the modifier stack in the tool bar but it uses a very different format for declaring a class

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Panel, UIList
from bl_ui.properties_data_modifier import DATA_PT_modifiers as PT_MOD

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return (context.object is not None)

def make_panel(name, poll, funcs):
    overwrites = {
        "bl_space_type": "VIEW_3D",
        "bl_region_type": "TOOLS",
        "bl_label": "Test",
        "bl_context": "objectmode",
        "bl_category": "Test",
        "poll": poll,
        "draw": getattr(funcs, "draw")
    }

    for f in dir(funcs):
        if f.isupper():
            overwrites[f] = getattr(funcs, f)

    return type(name, (Panel,), overwrites)

RigPanel = make_panel("OpenStudioAddRigPanel", poll, funcs=PT_MOD)

def register(): bpy.utils.register_class(RigPanel)
def unregister(): bpy.utils.unregister_class(RigPanel)
if __name__ == "__main__": register()
```

This is what I tried:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Panel, UIList
from bl_ui.properties_data_modifier import DATA_PT_modifiers as PT_MOD


class ObjectLayer(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_label = "ObjectLayer"
bl_idname = "ObjectLayer"
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
bl_category = "Claas"


def poll(cls, context):
return (context.object is not None)


def draw(self, context):
layout = self.layout

ob = context.object

layout.operator_menu_enum("object.modifier_add", "type")

for md in ob.modifiers:
    box = layout.template_modifier(md)
    if box:
        # match enum type to our functions, avoids a lookup table.
        getattr(self, md.type)(box, ob, md)


def make_panel(name, poll, draw, funcs):
overwrites = {
    "bl_space_type": "VIEW_3D",
    "bl_region_type": "TOOLS",
    "bl_label": "Test",
    "bl_context": "objectmode",
    "bl_category": "Test",
    "poll": poll,
    "draw": draw
}

for f in dir(funcs):
    if f.isupper():
        overwrites[f] = getattr(funcs, f)

return type(name, (Panel,), overwrites)

RigPanel = make_panel("OpenStudioAddRigPanel", poll, draw, funcs=PT_MOD)

def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectLayer)

def unregister():
bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectLayer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
register()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\untitled.blend\Text", line 58, in 
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\untitled.blend\Text", line 52, in register
AttributeError: expected Panel, ObjectLayer class to have an "draw" attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regular class definition scheme as shown in the TextEditor Python Templates -- unless you have a good reason to use a *class Factory*.

As Sambler [shows in the new answer to the previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44191/47): You can do this much simpler with standard class definitions -- the use of the "class *Factory*" was not appropriate in this scenario because it wasn't the least complicated solution.

---

However, to answer this question anyway; the *make_panel* function is what we might call a "class *Factory*".

**Positive**

- It generates unique classes on the fly, requiring little code to  individualize each class. Especially useful if you need many classes which differ only in small but important ways.
- This avoids explicitly writing the full class out in code for every class if you just need to change a couple of lines or functions per class.

**negative**

- The downside to a class factory is it becomes tricky to reason about the code, especially for newcomers. If you don't know how to introspect a class it becomes a bit of a black-box.
- classes generated this way must be registered with `bpy.utils.register_class(...)`

  - `register_module(__name__)` won't find these classes automatically.

How to use such things correctly is better discussed on a programming QA like StackOverflow. See [this question / answer " How can I dynamically create derived classes from a base class "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class) . If that question is over the top of your head, probably wait till you get more Python experience before using the code.